# Is $X_{0}$ a subset of $X_{0}\sqcup X_{1}$?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Since the disjoint union of $X_{0}= \{x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}\}$ and $X_{1}= \{x_{1}, x_{2}\}$ is: $ X_{0}\sqcup X_{1}= \{(x_{1},0), (x_{2},0), (x_{3},0), (x_{1},1), (x_{2},1)\}$ I have to ask; is $X_{0}$ a subset of $X_{0}\sqcup X_{1}$? I just would like to know because I can't tell if there ought to be an *inclusion function*.

The *inclusion function* is the identity map $id: x \mapsto x$ but the elements of the disjoint union are indexed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, formally $X_0$ is not a subset of $X_0\sqcup X_1$. But there is a natural injective function

$$i:X_0\to X_0\sqcup X_1$$
$$i(x)=(x,0)$$

and therefore many authors will treat $X_0$ as a subset of $X_0\sqcup X_1$ via the embedding above, i.e. they will replace $X_0$ with the image $i(X_0)$. This is so natural that most authors will completely forget about indexing.